# Where is Ivy repository for xuggle-utils.jar?

Tags: java, repository, ivy, xuggler

I am trying to compile Xuggler under windows. It's `ivy.xml` file contains the following dependency:

```
<dependency org="xuggle" name="xuggle-utils" rev="latest.integration" conf="test" changing="true"/>
```

Unfortunately, this dependency cannot be found int any repository, configured in this project.

Where is up to date version of repo for xuggler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in Xuggler 5.3 (launches next week).  It is already in the github project as [cross_compile 1489166].

https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler

Enjoy.

Comment: Mr. Xuggle if you could please help me with getting started. I don't use Ivy or Maven and don't know what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-working-with-xuggler

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a file `http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/java/ivysettings.xml`which suggests `http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/` as the repo, so you might try that one.

A problem might be that the repository might not be queryable and thus `rev="latest.integration"` might cause problems, since Ivy can't query the repo for the available versions.

Comment: Yes this repository looks obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

The settings file in the project's source does not appear to be working.

I think discovered the locations of both the xuggle jars and the secondary repository used to host the module's transitive dependencies (contained in the xuggle module ivy.xml).

Example ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml files included below.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.demo" module="demo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile"/>
        <conf name="runtime" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="xuggle" name="xuggle-utils" rev="latest.integration" conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <url name="xuggle">
            <ivy pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            <artifact pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <url name="red5">
            <artifact pattern="http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="xuggle" resolver="xuggle" />
        <module organisation="red5"   resolver="red5" />
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```